# c++11 and gcc: internal compiler error: in convert_move

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have the following code:

```
typedef int  __v8si __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (32)));

class T
{
public:
   __v8si v;

   __attribute__((target("avx2")))
   T(int p ):v(__extension__ __v8si{p,p,p,p,p,p,p,p}){}

   __attribute__((target("avx2")))
   T(__v8si p):v(p){}

   __attribute__((target("avx2")))
   T operator * ( T  b ) const
   {
      return __builtin_ia32_pmulld256( v , b.v ) ;
   }
};

void h(int *);

__attribute__((target("default")))
void h(int *)
{
}

__attribute__((target("avx2")))
void h(int *)
{
 const T a(1);
 const T b(2);
 const T c (a * b);
}

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

If I try to compile it,
I have the following error:

```
$ gcc test.cpp -std=c++11

test.cpp: In member function 'T T::operator*(T) const':
test.cpp:17:48: internal compiler error: in convert_move, at expr.c:315
       return __builtin_ia32_pmulld256( v , b.v ) ;
                                                ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
```

I have tried to compile it with various gcc versions:
4.9.2, 5.3 and several other versions.

Have you any ideas why it happens, and how could I solve the problem?

`gcc test.cpp -std=c++11 -mavx2` works.

`gcc test.cpp -std=c++11 -O1` works.

but I want to compile the code with `-O0`

**Update 1.** I've filed a bug report. The report is available here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77952

Comment: Not really a question for SO. You hit a bug in the compiler, report it just like the instructions told you.

Comment: @Art: Probably I do something wrong

Comment: When the error message says "internal error" and "Please submit a full bug report," is one of the few times in your developer life when you can safely say "it's a compiler error". In all other cases blaming the compiler is just a lie we tell ourselves to feel better about our terrible code, but when the compiler actually admits to having a bug and asks for a report, it's safe to assume the compiler is right.

Comment: @Art: I've filed the bugreport already. Let's wait for the answer

Comment: Did you ever work around this issue? There's been no update on the bug report except an acknowledgement

Comment: @SteveCox: No, I didn't

Comment: Ok i worked around this by returning a reference, which is a  horrific workaround, and probably not always possible. Hopefully they fix this soon. writing for avx2 is painful because of this